# pgfplots fails to graph the function [sin(x)]^100

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, function

The image shows that the graph of [sin(x)]^100 (in red) lies below the x-axis in four small intervals, as the function is non-negative its graph should be on or above the x-axis. So there is an error when plotting the graph of [sin(x)]^100, but I have no idea how to correct it.

I would appreciate anyone willing to point me to a solution or paths to it.

[image]

The image was generated with the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xscale=1.5,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left, 
        axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,xmax=6.7,ymax=1.3,
        every inner x axis line/.append style={- 
             stealth},xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f_n(x)$,]
        \addplot+ [domain=0:2*pi,smooth,mark=none,blue] {sin(deg(x))};
        \addplot+ [domain=0:2*pi,smooth,mark=none,red] {sin(deg(x))^100};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source of your problem is use `smooth` (spline function) on too small number of sampled. So, if you:

- increase number od samples, for example to 401,
- remove `smooth` instruction,

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xmax=6.7,   ymax=1.3,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f_n(x)$,
%
clip=false,
legend style = {at ={(0.8,0.8)}, anchor=west,
                font=\scriptsize, 
                legend cell align=left,
                },  
%
trig format=rad,
domain=0:2*pi,  samples=401,
no marks,
                ]
\addplot    {sin(x)};
\addplot    {sin(x)^100};

\legend{$\sin(x)$, $(\sin(x))^{100}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you will get desired result:

[image]

Off-topic:

- clear-up `axis` preamble (too many axis instructions where the last ones overwrite the first ones)
- move common option from `addplot` to `axis` preamble

**Edit (1):**
To diagram is added legend.

**Edit (2):**
A version of your diagram where x ticks are given in radians and function curves are thicker (for exercise):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x = 12mm,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmax=7,   ymax=1.4,
    xlabel=$x$ (rad), ylabel=$f_n(x)$,
% legend
clip=false,
legend style = {at ={(0.8,0.8)}, anchor=west,
                font=\scriptsize,
                legend cell align=left,
                },
% new
trig format=rad,
      xtick = {pi/4,    pi/2,     3*pi/4,   pi,
               5*pi/4, 3*pi/2,    7*pi/4,  2*pi},
xticklabels = {$\pi/4$, $\pi/2$, $3\pi/4$, $\pi$,
               $5\pi/4$, $3\pi/2$, $7\pi/4$, $2\pi$},
  tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
x tick label style = {yshift=-2ex, anchor=center},
extra y ticks = {0},
%
domain=0:2*pi,  samples=401,
no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
                ]
\addplot    {sin(x)};
\addplot    {sin(x)^100};

\legend{$\sin(x)$, $(\sin(x))^{100}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: for large n,  (sin x)^n is very very close to exp(n (x-pi/2)^2/2). This can help for easier plotxand computation.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `samples=100` to your code for sin(x)^100, it should fix the problem. This is the new code:

```
begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xscale=1.5,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left, 
        axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,xmax=6.7,ymax=1.3,
        every inner x axis line/.append style={- 
             stealth},xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f_n(x)$,]
        \addplot+ [domain=0:2*pi,smooth,mark=none,blue] {sin(deg(x))};
        \addplot+ [samples=100,domain=0:2*pi,smooth,mark=none,red] {sin(deg(x))^100};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Wonderful answers.

Please accept my best regards

Benaia

Comment: @BenaiaSobreiradeJesusLima, **you** have to accept the answer (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852))